# Cursor in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, cursor, plpgsql

I want to use a cursor inside the function but then I have a error about definition of one variable, take a look and help please :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION curson_func (
start_date timestamp,
end_date timestamp)
RETURNS SETOF integer AS $$

DECLARE
level_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
    login_event.player_id,
    registration.country_id
FROM
    "fish-tsg".registration
LEFT JOIN
    "fish-tsg".login_event USING (player_id)
WHERE
    ts >= start_date AND ts <= end_date ;

level_cursor_row "fish-tsg".login_event%ROW_TYPE;

BEGIN 
OPEN level_cursor;
LOOP FETCH level_cursor INTO level_cursor_row;
EXIT WHEN level_cursor_row = null;
END LOOP;
CLOSE level_cursor;

RETURN level_cursor_row;

END $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And error that I got:

```
ERROR:  invalid type name ""fish-tsg".login_event%ROW_TYPE"
LINE 20: level_cursor_row "fish-tsg".login_event%ROW_TYPE;
```

Comment: [Copying Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-TYPE)

Comment: Additionally there are errors related to working with cursors. Look at [this tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-cursor/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PostgreSQL are you using? Your syntax is (besides the many errors in your code) very old style, and it is a lot easier now. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cursor_func (_start_date timestamp, _end_date timestamp) RETURNS TABLE (player_id int, country_id int) AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  _level record;
BEGIN 
  FOR _level IN -- cursor is opened automatically
    SELECT login_event.player_id, registration.country_id
    FROM "fish-tsg".registration
    LEFT JOIN "fish-tsg".login_event USING (player_id)
    WHERE ts BETWEEN _start_date AND _end_date
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT _level;
  END LOOP;
  -- note that cursor is auto-closed

  RETURN;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But you should likely benefit from something way simpler without a cursor at all:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cursor_func (_start_date timestamp, _end_date timestamp) RETURNS TABLE (player_id int, country_id int) AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
  RETURN QUERY
    SELECT login_event.player_id, registration.country_id
    FROM "fish-tsg".registration
    LEFT JOIN "fish-tsg".login_event USING (player_id)
    WHERE ts BETWEEN _start_date AND _end_date;

  RETURN;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And even more simply:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cursor_func (_start_date timestamp, _end_date timestamp) RETURNS TABLE (player_id int, country_id int) AS $BODY$
  SELECT login_event.player_id, registration.country_id
  FROM "fish-tsg".registration
  LEFT JOIN "fish-tsg".login_event USING (player_id)
  WHERE ts BETWEEN $1 AND $2
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've have something new, but I receive **ONLY ONE ROW**. Where is the problem ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bi.temp_cursor()  
RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
ref refcursor;
ref2 RECORD;

BEGIN
OPEN ref FOR SELECT player_id, ts FROM "fish-tsg".registration LIMIT 100;
FETCH ref INTO ref2;
    LOOP
        RETURN ref2;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    END LOOP;   
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*SQL query is sample, problem is the cursor in pl/pgsql*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the better approach to what you need is to use a view instead of a function.

First, create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW temp_view
as
SELECT
    login_event.player_id,
    registration.country_id,
    ts
FROM "fish-tsg".registration
LEFT JOIN "fish-tsg".login_event USING (player_id)
```

And then, execute a normal select using the view name where you usually put the table name:

```
select player_id, country_id
from temp_view
where ts between $start_date AND $end_date;
```